# Cordova SQLite - get results from a sequence of SELECT queries

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I have a Cordova mobile app using a SQLite database. I'm using the `cordova-sqlite-storage` plugin. I need to perform two selects one after another and get the results. Is it possible to avoid the nesting? And if so, how? Couldn't find any example on how to do it.

P.S. I need to exit the function with both results from both queries

```
ctx.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM cards WHERE lastupdate > ?;", [lastSync], function(tx, rs) {
        // get the result here from first select
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM events WHERE lastupdate > ?;", [lastSync], function(tx, rs) {
            // get the result from second select and return
            // return with results from both queries
        }, function(tx, error) {
            // fail
        });
    }, function(tx, error) {
        // fail
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need the result of the first select, I don't think you need to nest. Something like this should work:

```
var result1, result2; 
ctx.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM cards WHERE lastupdate > ?;", [lastSync], function(tx, rs) {
        // get the result here from first select
        result1 = ...;
    }, function(tx, error) {
        // fail
    });
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM events WHERE lastupdate > ?;", [lastSync], function(tx, rs) {
        // get the result from second select and return
        result2 = ...;
    }, function(tx, error) {
        // fail
    });
}, null, function() {
    //do something with results;
});
```

The plugin should still queue and execute them in order.

Comment: ops, I'm sorry.. I do need to exit the function with both results.. I edited the question

Comment: in that case I'd suggest adding a success handler to the transaction. If your function has a callback or promise you can resolve it with the results there

Comment: I added the success handler to my answer

Comment: "null" is the error function (not needed here). Is that right?

Comment: That's correct. I don't know why the order of success and error handlers is different. For the most part the plugin just follows the websql spec which defines it like that. https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/